# Combine multiple Collections into a single logical Collection?

Tags: java, collections, guava

Assume, I have a constant number of collections (e.g. 3 ArrayLists) as members of a class. Now, I want to expose all the elements to other classes so they can simply iterate over all elements (ideally, read only).
I'm using guava collections and I wonder how I could use guava iterables/iterators to generate a logical view on the internal collections **without** making temporary copies.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

With Guava, you can use [`Iterables.concat(Iterable<T> ...)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable...%29), it creates a live view of all the iterables, concatenated into one (if you change the iterables, the concatenated version also changes). Then wrap the concatenated iterable with [`Iterables.unmodifiableIterable(Iterable<T>)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#unmodifiableIterable%28java.lang.Iterable%29) (I hadn't seen the read-only requirement earlier).

From the [`Iterables.concat( .. )`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable...%29) JavaDocs:

> Combines multiple iterables into a
>   single iterable. The returned iterable
>   has an iterator that traverses the
>   elements of each iterable in inputs.
>   The input iterators are not polled
>   until necessary. The returned
>   iterable's iterator supports `remove()`
>   when the corresponding input iterator
>   supports it.

While this doesn't explicitly say that this is a live view, the last sentence implies that it is (supporting the [`Iterator.remove()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) method only if the backing iterator supports it is not possible unless using a live view)

**Sample Code:**

```
final List<Integer> first  = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3);
final List<Integer> second = Lists.newArrayList(4, 5, 6);
final List<Integer> third  = Lists.newArrayList(7, 8, 9);
final Iterable<Integer> all =
    Iterables.unmodifiableIterable(
        Iterables.concat(first, second, third));
System.out.println(all);
third.add(9999999);
System.out.println(all);
```

**Output:**

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9999999]

---

Edit:

By Request from Damian, here's a similar method that returns a live Collection View

```
public final class CollectionsX {

    static class JoinedCollectionView<E> implements Collection<E> {

        private final Collection<? extends E>[] items;

        public JoinedCollectionView(final Collection<? extends E>[] items) {
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean addAll(final Collection<? extends E> c) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {
            for (final Collection<? extends E> coll : items) {
                coll.clear();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean contains(final Object o) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean containsAll(final Collection<?> c) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return !iterator().hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            return Iterables.concat(items).iterator();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean remove(final Object o) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean removeAll(final Collection<?> c) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean retainAll(final Collection<?> c) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            int ct = 0;
            for (final Collection<? extends E> coll : items) {
                ct += coll.size();
            }
            return ct;
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] toArray() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean add(E e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Returns a live aggregated collection view of the collections passed in.
     * <p>
     * All methods except {@link Collection#size()}, {@link Collection#clear()},
     * {@link Collection#isEmpty()} and {@link Iterable#iterator()}
     *  throw {@link UnsupportedOperationException} in the returned Collection.
     * <p>
     * None of the above methods is thread safe (nor would there be an easy way
     * of making them).
     */
    public static <T> Collection<T> combine(
        final Collection<? extends T>... items) {
        return new JoinedCollectionView<T>(items);
    }

    private CollectionsX() {
    }

}
```

Comment: How would I prevent the user from removing elements? Is there a nicer way than wrapping the lists into unmodifiableLists?

Comment: @jn_ just wrap it in [`Iterables.unmodifiableIterable(iterable)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#unmodifiableIterable%28java.lang.Iterable%29)

Comment: What about collections? `Iterables.concat` produces an `Iterable`, not `Collection`. I would need a `Collection` view.

Comment: @Damian the only useful feature of that would be to have an aggregated size() method. All other methods in the Collection interface would either have undefined semantics (add etc) or miserable performance (contains etc).

Comment: But you can of course use the Iterable created by Iterables.concat to populate a Collection using one of the Guava factory methods in Sets or Lists, but that would not be a live view.

Comment: @Sean, yes - `size()` is what I need. `add()` throwing an exception is good - I don't care about this method. Collections API is broken and noone can do anything about it. `Collection.add()`, `Iterator.remove()`, blah.

Answer (score 107):

Plain Java 8 solutions using a [`Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

### Constant number

Assuming `private Collection<T> c, c2, c3`.

One solution:

```
public Stream<T> stream() {
    return Stream.concat(Stream.concat(c.stream(), c2.stream()), c3.stream());
}
```

Another solution:

```
public Stream<T> stream() {
    return Stream.of(c, c2, c3).flatMap(Collection::stream);
}
```

### Variable number

Assuming `private Collection<Collection<T>> cs`:

```
public Stream<T> stream() {
    return cs.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you're using at least Java 8, see [my other answer](//stackoverflow.com/questions/4896662/combine-multiple-collections-into-a-single-logical-collection/23998250#23998250).

If you're already using Google Guava, see [Sean Patrick Floyd's answer](//stackoverflow.com/questions/4896662/combine-multiple-collections-into-a-single-logical-collection/4896878#4896878).

If you're stuck at Java 7 and don't want to include Google Guava, you can write your own (read-only) `Iterables.concat()` using no more than `Iterable` and `Iterator`:

### Constant number

```
public static <E> Iterable<E> concat(final Iterable<? extends E> iterable1,
                                     final Iterable<? extends E> iterable2) {
    return new Iterable<E>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<E>() {
                final Iterator<? extends E> iterator1 = iterable1.iterator();
                final Iterator<? extends E> iterator2 = iterable2.iterator();

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return iterator1.hasNext() || iterator2.hasNext();
                }

                @Override
                public E next() {
                    return iterator1.hasNext() ? iterator1.next() : iterator2.next();
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

### Variable number

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <E> Iterable<E> concat(final Iterable<? extends E>... iterables) {
    return concat(Arrays.asList(iterables));
}

public static <E> Iterable<E> concat(final Iterable<Iterable<? extends E>> iterables) {
    return new Iterable<E>() {
        final Iterator<Iterable<? extends E>> iterablesIterator = iterables.iterator();

        @Override
        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            return !iterablesIterator.hasNext() ? Collections.emptyIterator()
                                                : new Iterator<E>() {
                Iterator<? extends E> iterableIterator = nextIterator();

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return iterableIterator.hasNext();
                }

                @Override
                public E next() {
                    final E next = iterableIterator.next();
                    findNext();
                    return next;
                }

                Iterator<? extends E> nextIterator() {
                    return iterablesIterator.next().iterator();
                }

                Iterator<E> findNext() {
                    while (!iterableIterator.hasNext()) {
                        if (!iterablesIterator.hasNext()) {
                            break;
                        }
                        iterableIterator = nextIterator();
                    }
                    return this;
                }
            }.findNext();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new `List` and `addAll()` of your other `List`s to it. Then return an unmodifiable list with `Collections.unmodifiableList()`.

Comment: That would create a new temporary collection which is potentially quite expensive

Comment: Expensive *how*, the underlying objects in the lists aren't copied and `ArrayList` just allocates the space and calls `System.arraycopy()` under the hood. Can't get much more efficient than that.

Comment: How is copying a whole collection for every iteration **not** expensive? Moreover, you can get better than that, see Seans answer.

Comment: It also uses a native implementation to copy the memory, it doesn't iterate through the array.

Comment: Well if it is copying the array it is certainly an O(n) algorithm which does **not** scale and has the same complexity as iterating over the array once. Assume each list contains a million elements, then I need to copy a few million elements, only to iterate over them. Bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for that:

EDIT - changed code a little bit

```
public static <E> Iterable<E> concat(final Iterable<? extends E> list1, Iterable<? extends E> list2)
{
    return new Iterable<E>()
    {
        public Iterator<E> iterator()
        {
            return new Iterator<E>()
            {
                protected Iterator<? extends E> listIterator = list1.iterator();
                protected Boolean checkedHasNext;
                protected E nextValue;
                private boolean startTheSecond;

                public void theNext()
                {
                    if (listIterator.hasNext())
                    {
                        checkedHasNext = true;
                        nextValue = listIterator.next();
                    }
                    else if (startTheSecond)
                        checkedHasNext = false;
                    else
                    {
                        startTheSecond = true;
                        listIterator = list2.iterator();
                        theNext();
                    }
                }

                public boolean hasNext()
                {
                    if (checkedHasNext == null)
                        theNext();
                    return checkedHasNext;
                }

                public E next()
                {
                    if (!hasNext())
                        throw new NoSuchElementException();
                    checkedHasNext = null;
                    return nextValue;

                }

                public void remove()
                {
                    listIterator.remove();
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Your implementation flips the roles of `hasNext()` and `next()`. The first changes your iterator's state while the second doesn't. It should be the other way around. Calling `next()` without calling `hasNext()` will always yield `null`. Calling `hasNext()` without calling `next()` will throw away elements. Your `next()` doesn't throw `NoSuchElementException` either, but instead returns `null`.

Comment: You have re-invented `org.apache.commons.collections4.IterableUtils.chainedIterable()`