# Generic Questions. Inheritance

Tags: java, generics

I am tired of the below issue. please help?
I have a below interface

```
/**
* <T> Type of Timestamp. For ex: Date, long, Calendar etc
* 
*/
public interface TimeStamp<T> extends Comparable<TimeStamp<T>>
{

/**
* Returns the timestamp. 
 * @return 
*/
 public T getTimeStamp();

 }
```

And in my code I have 2 lists:

```
    List<FileTimeStamp> f = new ArrayList<FileTimeStamp>();
    List<DefaultTimeStamp> t = new ArrayList<DefaultTimeStamp>();
```

I want to create a method that takes the above 2 lists containing TimeStamps and then merge them.
Ex:

```
void merge(List<TimeStamp> l1, List<TimeStamp> l2)
{
    l1.addAll(l2);
    Collections.sort(l1);
}
```

But the above generates compile time warnings.

> void merge(List l1, List l2)
>    missing type arguments for generic class TimeStamp
>    where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends Object declared in interface TimeStamp

How should I define the above method without any compile time warnings? What should be my `void merge(List<TimeStamp<????>> l1, List<TimeStamp<????>> l2)` ???? in left be?

Comment: Your method merge() is correct. All you need to do is initialize your f and t with proper data types to support <T>. Have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you care about type safety you must have equal types.

Solution for your question is:

```
public static <T> void  merge(List<T> left, List< ? extends T> right) {
         left.addAll(right);
}
```

How this will work:

```
  List<TimeStamp> timeList = new ArrayList<>();
  List<DefaultTimeStamp> defaultTimeList = new ArrayList<>();
  List<FileTimeStamp> fileTimeList = new ArrayList<>();
```

We well be able to perform:

```
 merge(timeList, defaultTimeList);
 merge(timeList, fileTimeList);

 merge(timeList, timeList);
 merge(defaultTimeList, defaultTimeList);
 merge(fileTimeList, fileTimeList);
```

We will not be able to:

```
 merge(fileTimeList, defaultTimeList);
```

The key to success is that `right` list item must be assignalbe to type of items in `left` list.

After merge you wan to sort, this is another part of task. To sort List the class that is stored in list should implements interface `Comparable`

So we end up with structure like this:

```
    public interface TimeStamp extends Comparable<TimeStamp> {

    }

    public interface DefaultTimeStamp extends TimeStamp {

    }

    public interface FileTimeStamp extends TimeStamp {

    }
```

To merge and sort we need to limie the `T` to type that implements [`Comparable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) at least on `T`

And this look like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void  mergeAndSort(List<T> left, List< ? extends T> right) {

    left.addAll(right);
    Collections.sort(left);
}
```

So we can say that you have what you want.

---

But i would separate the operations and use  [Iterables.concat(Iterable ...)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html), in [Combine multiple Collections into a single logical Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896662/combine-multiple-collections-into-a-single-logical-collection) is describe how it works; for merging and after that i would sort it.

Comment: But how do we deal with type of TimeStamp. We need to declare a type to incorporate - public T getTimeStamp(); method.

Comment: The answer do not covere that, it was more about how generic works. If you still have problems i will edit the answer in few hours to adapt it to your case. but i thik that at this point you should manage to do it by your selft.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. This is just for learning purpose. I have the running code, just that I am trying to refine it. Ideally one would want TimeStamp to have the type defined.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,

```
public interface TimeStamp<T> extends Comparable<TimeStamp<T>> {
    public T getTimeStamp();
}
public class FileTimeStamp<T> implements TimeStamp<T>{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TimeStamp<T> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public T getTimeStamp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
public class DefaultTimeStamp<T> implements TimeStamp<T>{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TimeStamp<T> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public T getTimeStamp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
public class Abcd<T> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<FileTimeStamp<Date>> l1 = new ArrayList<FileTimeStamp<Date>>();
        List<DefaultTimeStamp<Long>> l2 = new ArrayList<DefaultTimeStamp<Long>>();
        Abcd abcd = new Abcd();
        abcd.merge(l1, l2);
    }

    void merge(List<TimeStamp> l1, List<TimeStamp> l2)  {
        l1.addAll(l2);
        Collections.sort(l1);
    }
}
```