# How do I concatenate two lists to create a 3rd?

Tags: java, guava

I've been googling for this, and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896662/combine-multiple-collections-into-a-single-logical-collection).  There is an [Iterables.concat](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable)) in guava.  But this returns an `Iterable` and the next thing I want to do is sort the result.  `Collections.sort` takes in a `List`, not an `Iterable` so I'd have to convert the `Iterable` into a `List` as my next step.  Is there a more direct way to combine two `List`s and then sort the result?

Comment: `Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.concat(...))`?

Comment: added as an answer (wasn't sure I understood the question, so I commented)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I join two lists in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189559/how-do-i-join-two-lists-in-java)

Comment: @Raedwald one minor difference is his question says, "no external libraries"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Something> list = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.concat(...));
Collections.sort(list);
```

might be a solution here.

Comment: Shorter and likely faster: `Ordering.natural().sortedCopy(Iterables.concat(...))`

Answer (score 6):

In Java 8:

```
List<E> sorted = Stream.concat(l1.stream(), l2.stream())
                       .sorted()
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

List has the `addAll(Collection`) method, which I think is useful for your purpose. You can copy the first list and make something like this:

```
copyList1.addAll(list2);
```

Answer (score 2):

If a SortedSet is also good as return type (I find this is one you really want in most cases) you can do:

```
FluentIterable.from( list1 ).concat( list2 ).toSortedSet( Ordering.natural() );
```

Comment: FYI, there's also `toSortedList(Ordering.natural())`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
List<Something> list1;
List<Something> list2;

list1.addAll(list2);
Collections.sort( list1 );
```

(Assuming your list is a list of `Comparable`s)

If you don't want to modify `list1`, you can use:

```
List<Something> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.copy( list3, list1 );
list3.addAll( list2 );
Collections.sort( list3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 (replace String with whatever type your list contains):

```
List<String> newList = Stream.concat(listOne.stream(), listTwo.stream()).collect(Collectors.<String>toList());
```

This will concatenate your two lists to create a new, 3rd list. You can then sort it as you mentioned in your post by using `Collections.sort`:

```
Collections.sort(newList);
```

See also: [How do I join two lists in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189559/how-do-i-join-two-lists-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work with JAVA 8 Stream API

```
class T {
     @Getter private int sortingProperty; 
    }
 List<T> list3 Stream.of(list1OfT,list2OfT)    
                                 .sorted(Comparing(T::getSortingProperty))
                                 .collect(toList());
```