# How to Check if a TreeMap is submap of another TreeMap in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

New to Java 8, and am unable to figure this one out.
I have two maps of type `TreeMap<Long, Integer>`, one is called `patternMap` and the other `answerMap`.

`patternMap` is hardcoded to look for a particular pattern of key-value pairs, so there are many `patternMap`'s, and their size is always less than or equal to `answerMap`.
I would like to check which `patternMap`s are a match in `answerMap`, and I mean I need exact match on key and value both, not just one.

I'm unable to use the `submap` method, because `patternMap` may not have a contiguous range of keys.
The obvious way is to walk through the `patternMap` and check each `Map.Entry` object with `equals` method. However, I have many `patternMap`'s to check against a particular `answerMap`, so I'm curious to know if there is a better way, probably using lambdas/streams. 
I also cannot modify the `answerMap` or the `patternMap`, so this has to be a non-mutating function.
I use `TreeMap`'s because the ordering is important for the application.

There is no code here because I haven't found a way to do this, but pseudo-code would look like this:

```
for every patternMap in the Collection {
   if answerMap contains patternMap, make a note
}
```

EDIT: Here are some definitions(this isn't working code, but hopefully makes question clearer:

```
 private static final TreeMap<Long, Integer> patternMap1;
 private static final TreeMap<Long, Integer> patternMap2;
 private static final ArrayList<TreeMap> listOfPatternMaps;
 private TreeMap<Long, Integer> answerMap;

  private Set<TreeMap<Long, Integer>> findPatterns(TreeMap answerMap) {
       this.answerMap = answerMap;
       for(patternMap : listOfPatternMaps) {
           if answerMap contains patternMap {
              make a note
           }
       } 
       return setOfMatchedPatterns;
  }
```

Comment: When you are doing `if answerMap contains patternMap`, is this referring to all the key-value pairs in the patternMap matching some subset of the answerMap?

Comment: It would be helpful to see definitions of answerMap and patternMap, seeing actual code is better then reading about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine multiple Collections into a single logical Collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896662/combine-multiple-collections-into-a-single-logical-collection)

Comment: I hope that edit it pseudocode, because raw `TreeMap` is a big no, no.

Comment: @Smac89 - yes, answerMap contains questionID as key and answerChosen as value, and i want to see if the answers match a defined pattern of <question,answer>, so the pattern will be "subset" or submap" of answerMap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
answerMap.entrySet().containsAll(patternMap.entrySet())
```