# List view of concatenated lists

Tags: java, collections, view, lazy-evaluation

I want to create a list view that consists of the concatenation of a number of other lists.

Example:

```
List<Integer> l1 = Lists.newArrayList(1);
List<Integer> l2 = Lists.newArrayList(2);
List<Integer> l3 = Lists.newArrayList(3);

// This call should not copy any of the argument lists content
List<Integer> concatenation = new ConcatenationListView(l1, l2, l3);

System.out.println(concatenation); // Prints [1, 2, 3]
l3.add(4);
System.out.println(concatenation); // Prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

What kind of technique and or pattern can I use in Java to fulfill these requirements?

#### Details

- I want the concatenation to be lazy. (That's the meaning of "view" in this context.)
- I want change to the component lists the reflect on the concatenation. (Also the meaning of "view").
- The view need not to be modifiable.
- This is kind of the opposite of the [`List.subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) method.
- It is similar to what the Guava [`Iterables.concat`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat-java.lang.Iterable-) method do, but I need a list as the result, not an iterable.
- My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896662/combine-multiple-collections-into-a-single-logical-collection/4896878#4896878), but I need a `List` as the resulting concatenation, where the poster of the other question is content with an `Iterable` as the result.

Comment: *"Does such a thing exist somewhere?"* Off-topic because questions asking us to recommend or find a software library are off-topic for Stack Overflow. --- *"Or how do I implement it the best way?"* Question is off-topic because it is "too broad".

Comment: @Andreas: I think your nitpicking terribly, but I've edited the text to remove those phrases. The only problem I can see with the question is the concrete formulation of the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine multiple Collections into a single logical Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896662/combine-multiple-collections-into-a-single-logical-collection)

Comment: @basst314: No, it's not a duplicate. In that question the poster is content by having an `Interable` as the result. I need a `List`. I'll edit my question to explain that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an implementation of a class that acts as a view of the concatenation of a number of lists.

It didn't take many lines to do it:

```
/**
 * A list which acts as view of the concatenation of a number of lists.
 */
public class ListConcatenationView<E> extends AbstractList<E> {
    private final List<E>[] lists;
    
    @SafeVarargs
    public ListConcatenationView(List<E>... lists) {
        this.lists = lists;
    }
    
    @Override
    public E get(int ix) {
        if (ix < 0) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index negative: " + ix); 
        int localIx = ix;
        for (List<E> l : lists) {
            if (localIx < l.size()) return l.get(localIx);
            localIx -= l.size();
        }

        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index too large: " + ix);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        int size = 0;
        for (List<E> l : lists) {
            size += l.size();
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java class library does not have a composition class like that, so you would need to code it yourself.

Since you want the class to allow modifications to underlying lists, you wouldn't get better efficiency than O(L), where `L` is the number of lists managed by the view, because index translation would require you to walk the list of lists each time you need to read or insert at a specific index.

On the other hand, this makes implementation very straightforward - the code that translates the index would look as follows:

```
class ListView : List<T> {
    private List<List<T>> lists = ...
    public T get(int index) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i != lists.size() && index > lists.get(i).size()) {
            index -= lists.get(i++).size();
        }
        if (i == lists.size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        return lists.get(i).get(index);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: `class ListView : List<T>`? Are we reverting to C++? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I suspect I have to do something like this. It will probably not to too complicated. I think extending `AbstractList` is the right approach.

Comment: @Andreas: I consider it to be psudo-code so that's okay. :) Judging form the posters score in difference tags the syntax could be inspired by either C++ or C#...

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [Java8 Stream-API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) for this one.

```
Stream.of(l1, l2, l3)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This creates a Stream of the three lists, then concatenates all items from each list together by converting every list into a stream itself (`List::stream`) and flatMap-ing them together. After all it outputs every single element on the console.

Plus: Streams are lazy by default, meaning that

> computation on the source data is only performed when the terminal operation is initiated, and source elements are consumed only as needed.

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

Comment: No, this does not work unfortunately. The stream creation itself is lazy, when I turn the stream into a list that will be eager. My whole problem is that I need something that implements the `List` interface.

Comment: @Lii I found that this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896878/7474093). I marked the question as duplicate.

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. In that question the poster is content by having an `Interable` as the result. I need a `List`. I'll edit my question to explain that

Comment: @Lii Would it be an option to just return the lazily concatenated stream? That's pretty much like a read-only collection. Your callers could then lazily iterate through it, do whatever they want with the objects, but cannot modify the original collections ("view"). This would be much easier to achieve than an own list implementation.

Comment: I have to use a third-party API which takes a list. Also, I am interested in this for personal reasons.