# adding two arraylists into one

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to check branchList whether has same element or not, if same put branchList and tglList element separate arraylist and put that arraylist into another arraylist,

The result I want is BranchList1 have 2 arraylist where 1st arraylist contain for element '1' and 2nd arraylist contain element '2' and TglList1 have 2 arraylist as element, but what i get is both 1st and 2nd array get same value.

How can this be done?

```
ArrayList branchList = new ArrayList();
    branchList.add("1");
    branchList.add("1");
    branchList.add("1");
    branchList.add("2");
    branchList.add("2");
    branchList.add("2");

    ArrayList tglList = new ArrayList();
    tglList.add("5");
    tglList.add("10");
    tglList.add("20");
    tglList.add("100");
    tglList.add("500");
    tglList.add("1000");


    ArrayList newBranchList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList newTglList = new ArrayList();

    ArrayList BranchList1 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList TglList1 = new ArrayList();


    ArrayList abc = new ArrayList();
    String checkBranch = new String();

    for(int i=0;i<branchList.size();i++){
        String branch = branchList.get(i).toString();
        if(i==0 || checkBranch.equals(branch)){
            newBranchList.add(branch);
            newTglList.add(tglList.get(i).toString());
        }else{
            BranchList1.add(newBranchList);
            TglList1.add(newTglList);

            newBranchList.clear();
            newTglList.clear();

            newBranchList.add(branch);
            newTglList.add(tglList.get(i).toString());
        }
        if(i==(branchList.size()-1)){
            BranchList1.add(newBranchList);
            TglList1.add(newTglList);
        }
        checkBranch = branch;
    }

}
```

so expected result is as below:

```
BranchList1 = [ [1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
TglList1 = [[5,10,20],[50,100,200]]
```

but what I get is

```
BranchList1 = [ [2,2,2],[2,2,2]]
TglList1 = [[50,100,200],[50,100,200]]
```

How can I modify the code

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question.

Comment: Can you show an example of the start data lists and what the end data lists should look like?

Comment: finally solve, just change newBranchList.clear() to newBranchList = new ArrayList() and newTglList.clear() to newTglList = new ArrayList()

Comment: Should the title not be "how to merge two related arraylists based on values in the first one"? It seems that you are not "adding" anything, just rebuilding the  arraylists with sublists based on the values in the first one. On a related note, using independent ArrayLists for each property is discouraged - it would be a lot clearer to use custom classes with attributes for each property, and place *those* into a single arraylist...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I join two lists in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189559/how-do-i-join-two-lists-in-java)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I didn't thoroughly read through your code (and I don't quite get what you're asking for), but if you want to merge (add the elements of) `branchList` and `tglList` to `TglList1`, try this:

```
TglList1.addAll(branchList);
TglList1.addAll(tglList);
```

After that, `TglList1` should contain all elements of both lists. If you need the list to be sorted, you might want to call `Collections.sort(TglList1)` afterwards (just note that sorting strings might place "100" before "2", due to "1" being lexically smaller than "2").

Comment: TglList1.add(tglList)? tglList is a list, you need to use addAll there.