# Is it possible to have two 'mappedBy' properties in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

Assume I have the following entities:

```
public class Transfer {

...

private BankAccount senderAccount;
private BankAccount receiverAccount;

...

}
```

And

```
public class BankAccount {

...

private List<Transfer> transfers;

...

}
```

I want the transfers list inside my BankAccount class to hold both, sent and received transfers. Will it be possible to create an annotation like:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = 'senderAccount', mappedBy = 'receiverAccount')
```

If not, what will be the best approach to this?

EDIT: I want both sent and received transfers to be stored in one List.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Of course you cannot have it as you wrote it (compile error). The solution is simple:

```
public class BankAccount {

...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = 'receiverAccount')
private List<Transfer> transfersAsReceiver;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = 'senderAccount')
private List<Transfer> transfersAsSender;
...

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to hold all transfers in one list?

Comment: Not directly. You could add a property `getAllTransfers()` that [joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177004/adding-two-arraylists-into-one) both lists: `transfersAsReceiver` and `transfersAsSender`.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is:

```
public enum TransferDirection {
    SENDER,
    RECEIVER;
}

public class Transfer {

private TransferDirection direction;

private BankAccount account;

...

}
```

So you are storing one transfer object which is distinguished by the enum which identifies it as sender or receiver.

Comment: I want the transfer object to hold information about both entities, sender and receiver.

Comment: As Neil is saying, this is not possible.