# How to add more than one List<String> in Android?

Tags: java, android

How to assign more than one List in Android?

```
List<String> inc = dh.selectInct1();
    ArrayAdapter<String> inc1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list,R.id.textViewx,inc);
    lvinc.setAdapter(inc1);
lvinc.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Here `dh.selectInct1();` returns a list that is assigned into `inc`. Now I need to add one more list from database to this already existing `inc`. How to achieve it?

Comment: inc is List<String> and dh is object for datahelper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply join those two `List`s using `addAll(Collection c)`

```
List<String> inc = dh.selectInct1();
List<String> inc2 = dh.selectInct2();  //select your data to second list
inc.addAll(inc2); // join them together
ArrayAdapter<String> inc1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list,R.id.textViewx,inc);
lvinc.setAdapter(inc1);
lvinc.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

- [How do I join two lists in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189559/how-do-i-join-two-lists-in-java)
- [List.addAll() documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29)