# append two different ArrayList into one adpter

Tags: android

`listview` want to merge two different `arraylist` into one adapter.
i try using the position value of the `getView()` method but it not display correct data to `listview`first it display data from the one `arrayList` after it complete second `arraylist` should be start to display.

```
ArrayList<A> list1 = new  ArrayList<A>;
ArrayList<B> list2 = new ArrayList<B>;
```

i want to add this two list into one adapter.first i need to add list1 after list1 is complete data from list2 is display.i tried using position variable of `getView()` method but it not display correct data to me.

how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using adding both list into one list and set this common list to    adapter.

```
ArrayList<A> list1 = new  ArrayList<A>();
ArrayList<Object> object = new ArrayList<Object>();
list1.add(new A());
object.add(new A());
ArrayList<B> list2 = new ArrayList<B>();
list2.add(new B());
object.add(new B());
object.add(new B());
listadapter mAdapterSeeLatest ;
mAdapterSeeLatest = new listadapter (getParent(),R.layout.help_row,object); 
mCheckInListView.setAdapter(mAdapterSeeLatest);
private class listadapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    ArrayList<Object> ListObject;
    int srNumber = 1;
    public listadapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Object> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        ListObject = objects;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);    
        } 
        if(ListObject.get(position) instanceof A)
        {   

        }
        else if(ListObject.get(position) instanceof B)
        {
        }
    }

//now set this object ArrayList() into the List.
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just combine those two into one ArrayList?

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(listOne);
newList.addAll(listTwo);
```

Refer to this topic: [How do I join two lists in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189559/how-do-i-join-two-lists-in-java)