# Java Map to Set? Is there a way to implement pre-existing java libraries to allow a Map that contains Sets as values?

Tags: java, generics, set

I'm trying to create keys of id numbers and values of Sets, but I also need to write generic methods that iterate(requiring Iterable, thus why I'm attempting to use sets) over those Sets stuck in values. What is an efficient method for implementing an Iterator over some Generic values that are part of a Map object?

Comment: Did you mean something like : Map<String, Set<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

Comment: Use the Stream API? You can `map = stream.collect(groupingBy(..., toSet())` and then `map.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream)`

Comment: Why is `HashSet` unsuitable for your needs?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do what Kartic has over there. Is that how I should set up my Generic variables? It makes sense, since Sets implement Iterable, so technically any Set<String> should work for traversal and access to its String values. I'm going to try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your are describing, a `Map<X, Set<Y>>`, is often refered to as a "Set based MultiMap".

A popular implementation of such a Map is [Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html)

Aksing such a Map its `values()` will return a Collection that will contain all values of `Y` (and not all `Set<Y>` instances).

One can implement "by hand" such a Collection using basic Maps, but this proves surprisingly difficult to actualy implement right for all use cases, and preserve the Java Colletions Framework semantics. So using a library's implementation is usually the way to go.

Another option would be using the Stream API (Java8), with collectors such as `groupBy` to build the Map instance, and other stream operations to "flatten" the map's values when you want to iterate over the values (see [Flattening a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290935/flattening-a-collection) for example).

Below, find a SetMultiMap code sample

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Multimap<Integer, String> multiMap = HashMultimap.create();
multiMap.put(0, "key0_value0");
// Twice the same value for the same key, the Set<String> will "ignore" this
multiMap.put(0, "key0_value0"); 
multiMap.put(1, "key1_value0"); 
multiMap.put(1, "key1_value1"); 


System.out.println("Values for key 0");
System.out.println("----------------");
System.out.println(multiMap.get(0));
System.out.println("\r\nValues for key 1");
System.out.println("----------------");
System.out.println(multiMap.get(1));
System.out.println("\r\nAll values");
System.out.println("------------");
System.out.println(multiMap.values());

// Entries are all Integer/String associations
Collection<Entry<Integer, String>> entries = multiMap.entries();
System.out.println("\r\nNumber of entries : " + entries.size());

// We can build a standard Java Map out of the Multimap
Map<Integer, Collection<String>> realJavaMap = multiMap.asMap();
// The map's values are actually guaranteed to be Sets
System.out.println("Multimap as Map, values implement Set : " + Set.class.isAssignableFrom(realJavaMap.values().iterator().next().getClass()));

// The java Map is a live view of the multimap
realJavaMap.get(0).add("key0_value1"); // Actions on realJavaMap will update multimap

System.out.println("\r\nValues for key 0");
System.out.println("----------------");
System.out.println(multiMap.get(0));
```

}

This program outputs:

```
Values for key 0
----------------
[key0_value0]

Values for key 1
----------------
[key1_value1, key1_value0]

All values
------------
[key0_value0, key1_value1, key1_value0]

Number of entries : 3
Multimap as Map, value class is set : true

Values for key 0
----------------
[key0_value1, key0_value0]
```

Comment: Do I have to declare a generic type for hashmap or can I just start using its methods with a basic

HashMap hm = new HasMap();

Comment: I've added a code sample to my answer to show how the Guava based solution works. Unfortunately, I do not have access to a Java 8 editor right now so I can't post a stream API based example right now (I could guess and produce a half working implement but it probably wouldn't really work).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
class MapOfSetsIterable<V> implements Iterable<V> {

    private final Map<?, Set<V>> map;

    public MapOfSetsIterable(Map<?, Set<V>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<V> iterator() {
        return new MapOfSetsIterator();
    }

    private class MapOfSetsIterator implements Iterator<V> {

        final Iterator<Set<V>> sets = map.values().iterator();
        Iterator<V> i = sets.hasNext() ? sets.next().iterator() : Collections.EMPTY_SET.iterator();
        V next = null;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            while (next == null && (sets.hasNext() || i.hasNext())) {
                if (!i.hasNext() && sets.hasNext()) {
                    i = sets.next().iterator();
                }
                if (i.hasNext()) {
                    next = i.next();
                }
            }
            return next != null;
        }

        @Override
        public V next() {
            if (next == null) {
                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
            }
            V n = next;
            next = null;
            return n;
        }
    }
}

enum E {

    A, B
};

public void test() {
    Map<Integer, Set<E>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1, EnumSet.of(E.A));
    map.put(2, EnumSet.of(E.B));
    map.put(3, EnumSet.of(E.A, E.B));
    for (E e : new MapOfSetsIterable<>(map)) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```