# What is the java 8 equivalent to Guava's transformAndConcat?

Tags: java, java-8, guava

Lets assume I have a **class containing a List**, e.g.

```
 public static class ListHolder {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListHolder(final List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Let's furthermore assume I have a **whole list of instances of this class**:

```
    ListHolder listHolder1 = new ListHolder(Arrays.asList("String 1", "String 2"));
    ListHolder listHolder2 = new ListHolder(Arrays.asList("String 3", "String 4"));
    List<ListHolder> holders = Arrays.asList(listHolder1, listHolder2);
```

And now I need to **extract all Strings** to get a String List containing all Strings of all instances, e.g.:

```
[String 1, String 2, String 3, String 4]
```

With **Guava** this would look like this:

```
     List<String> allString = FluentIterable
            .from(holders)
            .transformAndConcat(
                    new Function<ListHolder, List<String>>() {
                        @Override
                        public List<String> apply(final ListHolder listHolder) {
                            return listHolder.getList();
                        }
                    }
            ).toList();
```

My question is **how can I achieve the same with the Java 8 stream API**?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
List<String> allString = holders.stream()
    .flatMap(h -> h.getList().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here is an older question about collection flattening: ([Flattening a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290935/flattening-a-collection))

Comment: or `.map(ListHolder::getList).flatMap(List::stream)`