# Convert List<List<Integer>> into int[]

Tags: java, arrays, list

I need to convert `List<List<Integer>> listoflist` into `int[] arr`. Straightforward solution is to use `for` loops, but is there a better approach?

Comment: The approach would still be the same

Comment: `list.stream().flatMap(l -> l.stream()).mapToInt(i -> i.intValue()).toArray()` . I wish the question wasn't closed as duplicate @redFIVE

Comment: @sidgate: Is it Java 8? I am using Java 7.

Comment: yes, java-8. don't have any better approach for Java 7

Comment: @sidgate beat me to it - ping me after you post this as an answer and I'd upvote. IMHO, though, using function references would be neater - `list.stream().flatMap(List::stream).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();`

Comment: @Mureinik yep much better

Comment: @Mureinik http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290935/flattening-a-collection looks like a much saner Java 8 flattening approach, without the double streaming

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290935/flattening-a-collection

Comment: @Mureinik: What is 'listoflist' and 'arr' in this line of code?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos - add `int[] arr = ` to the beginning, and change `list.stream()` to `listoflist.stream()`.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos `list` should be `listoflist`, right. This line returns the array, so you could do something like `int[] arr = listoflistsstream().flatMap(List::stream).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();`

Comment: @pvg though this question seems similar, it has a different solution and gives better alternative to age old problem of converting to primitive array