# How to Flatten a HashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, hash, java-8, flatten

I have a nested `HashMap` in this form:

```
{key1=val1, key2=val2, 
    key3=[
            {key4=val4, key5=val5}, 
            {key6=val6, key7=val7} 
        ]
}
```

I now want to flatten that map, so that all entries are on the same level:

```
{key1=val1, key2=val2, key4=val4, key5=val5,key6=val6, key7=val7}
```

---

When I try

```
map.values().forEach(map.get("key3")::addAll);
```

as [described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18290985/1170330), I get the following error:

```
invalid method reference
  cannot find symbol
    symbol:   method addAll(T)
    location: class Object
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Iterable
```

---

Is there any generic way to flatten any given `Map`?

Comment: a recursive function with an `instanceOf` check against `Map`, I assume

Comment: you can try to use flatMap() from Java Stream API

Comment: `map.get("key3")::addAll` makes no sense since you seem to have a `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: I would be really glad if you could share the type of your `Map` where the code that you've shared works.

Comment: What are the key value pairs in your hash map? key=>value, key=>array, key=>map?

Comment: Even for a map which allows that operation, what is it supposed to do when `map.values().forEach(map.get("key3")::addAll);` processes the entry for `"key3"`?

Comment: So what is the type of your `Map`? It can't be `Map<String, String>` if some of the entries are `Entry<String, Map<String, String>>`. You need to include the code for us to understand what you actually have.

Comment: @user1170330 Then your question doesn't make any sense, and you aren't working with a nested map then. (doesn't seem right to me)

Comment: @Lino: Sorry, the "main" map is  Map<String, Object>, all the contents within the this map are Strings.

Comment: @user1170330 No they are not. You are yourself saying some of them are a `Map`.

Comment: @nullpointer perhaps, but what I wanted to emphasizes, is that `map.values().forEach(…)` will process all entries, including the one the OP is adding to. So this will end up trying to add a list (or map) to itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but something like this might work.
Haven't checked all the syntax yet, so there might be some mistake somewhere.

```
Stream<Map.Entry<String, String>> flatten(Map<String, Object> map) {
  return map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(this::extractValue);         
}

Stream<Map.Entry<String, String>> extractValue(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry) {
   if (entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
      return Stream.of(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue()));
   } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map) {
      return flatten((Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue());
   }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
Map<String, String> flattenedMap = flatten(yourmap)
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: the `extractValue` method won't compile, a `return` is missing in case both `if`s fail

Comment: @Chirlo yes because i don't really know what the OP wants to do in that case

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a recursive helper method:

```
static void forEachValue(Map<String, Object> source, BiConsumer<? super String, ? super Object> action) {
    for (final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : source.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map) {
            forEachValue((Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue(), action);
        } else {
            action.accept(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Which then can be called like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = ...;

Map<String, Object> flattened = new HashMap<>();
forEachValue(map, map::put);
```

I've used this approach with the `BiConsumer` to not limit the method to only flatten the nested map into another map, but the caller may decide himself what he wants to do with every key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
Map<String, Object> flatenedMap = new HashMap<>();

    map.forEach((key, value) -> {
      if(value instanceof Map) {
        flatenedMap.putAll((Map) value);
      } else {
        flatenedMap.put(key, value);
      }
    });
```

If you have more than one level of nesting you can use recursive alg.

```
static Map<String, Object> flatMap(Map<String, Object> map) {
    Map<String, Object> flatenedMap = new HashMap<>();
    map.forEach((key, value) -> {
      if(value instanceof Map) {
        flatenedMap.putAll(flatMap((Map) value));
      } else {
        flatenedMap.put(key, value);
      }
    });

    return flatenedMap;
  }
```

Comment: and what do you do if there are more than just 2 nested layers of maps?

Comment: He wrote he has nested HashMap, if he has more than one layer of nesting then best would be to use some recursive alg

Comment: @Lino indeed, my bad.