# Concating ArrayLists in specific Order in Java

Tags: java, list

I have an ArrayList of HashMaps in Java and I want to append it to another similar list, 
Is there any way to do it so that the resulting array list retains the order.

for e.g.:

```
List<Map<String, String>> list1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
List<Map<String, String>> list1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

list1.add(hm1);
list1.add(hm2);
list1.add(hm3);

list2.add(hm4);
list2.add(hm5);
list2.add(hm6);
```

The new List that I want is:

```
//list 3 = list1 + list2;
list3 = {hm1, hm2, hm3, hm4, hm5, hm6};
```

How to do that?

Comment: NB: consider defining interfaces instead of actual classes and using `<>` to auto-infer generic types: `List<Map<String, String>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Thanks, for your first point, I have used List and Map interfaces now, but why is it better to auto-infer generic types instead of specifying string when I already know that it is supposed to hold string only?

Comment: to make the code less verbose and more readable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that easily in Java 8

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> newList = Stream.concat(listOne.stream(), 
   listTwo.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or alternatively in Java 7 and lower

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> newList = new ArrayList<>(list1.size() + list2.size());
newList.addAll(listOne);
newList.addAll(listTwo);
```

However you should be careful about memory leaks which can be caused by duplicate references to both lists, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13868352/1039952) answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `List.addAll())` method:

```
@Test
public void testConcat() {
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("A");
    list1.add("B");
    list1.add("C");

    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("D");
    list1.add("E");


    list1.addAll(list2);

    assertThat(list1).containsExactly("A","B","C","D","E");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> list3 = new ArrayList<>(list1);
list3.addAll(list2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) it used to inserts all of the elements in the specified collection into this list

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list3 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

list3.addAll(list1);
list3.addAll(list2);
```