# Merge each element of multiple lists into one Element and return another list in java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

for simplicity I have 2 lists of String and I need to  join the strings into one  and create another list. 
For eg --

```
List 1 = [a,b,c,d]
List 2 = [e,f,g,h]
```

I want the output as

```
List3 = [ae,bf,cg,dh]
```

I can do this using regular for loops. but dont know how to proceed for java8

I am trying to get myself thinking in n Java 8 :-)

Comment: So you're looking for a [zip](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip) operation?

Comment: in java 8 ? let me look ..

Comment: Duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189559/how-do-i-join-two-lists-in-java

The second answer shows an example for Java 8

Comment: @Rafa no, that's concatenating the two lists, which isn't what OP is asking.

Comment: yes.. I am looking for zip operation.. didnt know there was a term for that :-)  Thanks Andy..

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there's a better (easy) way to do this than to access the elements from the two lists by index:

```
List<String> zipped = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> list1.get(i) + list2.get(i))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: can I add another list after zipping the first  two lists into one before collecting into a list?

Comment: You haven't mentioned in this code, what `list` is. Also, this will throw `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` if `list.size()` is greater than the size of `list1` or that of `list2`.