# Trying to call an ArrayList from another method

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

So, I have 2 methods that return each a list of the same type of my business layer object class.

I am trying to make a new method that creates a new ArrayList of also the same type and adds those 2 lists to it.

Would anyone know how to call these lists into that combined list? This don't seem to work.

```
public response getlist1() {
    ....

    return list1;
}

public response getlist2() {
    ....

    return list2;
}

public response getCombinedList() {
     ArrayList<...> = new ArrayList<...>();     
     combinedList.add(list1);                                                
     combinedList.add(list2);
     ...   
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I join two lists in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189559/how-do-i-join-two-lists-in-java)

Comment: use `combindedList.addAll(list1);`

Comment: where are you calling getlist1() and getlist2()?

Comment: Try this, combinedList.add(getlist1()); combinedList.add(getlist2());

Comment: It doesn't seem to find list 1 and list 2

Comment: replace `list1` with `getList1()` and `list2` with `getList2()`

Comment: You may wish to brush up on the concept of variable scope (instance, class, local). If `list1` and `list1` cannot be found, they may be out of scope within `getCombinedList`.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, I would go with `addAll` method of the list:

```
public response getCombinedList(){
     ArrayList<...> = new ArrayList<...>();     
     combinedList.addAll(list1);                                                
     combinedList.addAll(list2);    
}
```