# Extend ImmutableList.of() by another List

Tags: java, guava, immutablelist

I want to simplify existing code that is related to ImmutableList.of() functionality

I alreaday tried to optimize the creation of the second List by eliminating the "new..." constructor, but of course I couldnt extend a immutable list by calling .add();

Current code:

```
static final ImmutableList<ProductCodeEnum> PRODUCTS = ImmutableList.of(ProductCodeEnum.A, ProductCodeEnum.B, ProductCodeEnum.C);


static final ImmutableList<ProductCodeEnum> PRODUCTS_EXTENDED_LIST = new ImmutableList.Builder<ProductCodeEnum>().addAll(PRODUCTS)
.add(ProductCodeEnum.D)
.add(ProductCodeEnum.E)
.build();
```

Expected code like:

```
static final ImmutableList<ProductCodeEnum> PRODUCTS = ImmutableList.of(ProductCodeEnum.A, ProductCodeEnum.B, ProductCodeEnum.C);


static final ImmutableList<ProductCodeEnum> PRODUCTS_EXTENDED = PRODUCTS + ImmutableList.of(ProductCodeEnum.D, ProductCodeEnum.E);
```

Comment: Your expected code is never going to work, there is no way to use the `+` operator to make lists in Java.

Comment: it is just a hint to which solution it could lead me. i need a equivalent to this

Comment: You have right code. The addAll() is right call for extending one list by another. In case of jdk8 check here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18687790/10099219

Comment: @PriyankaW mind that OP is working with `ImmutableList`s from (probably) guava, as the name says they're immutable and `addAll` can't be used

Comment: @Lino thank you for letting me know about guava; i missed to identify that. Then perhaps OP needs to use `ImmutableList.<>builder().addAll()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you use Guava ImmutableList?

In that case your code would look like this:

```
static final ImmutableList<ProductCodeEnum> PRODUCTS = ImmutableList.of(ProductCodeEnum.A, ProductCodeEnum.B, ProductCodeEnum.C);

static final ImmutableList<ProductCodeEnum> PRODUCTS_EXTENDED = ImmutableList.builder().addAll(PRODUCTS).add(ProductCodeEnum.D, ProductCodeEnum.E).build();
```

Comment: add(a,b) is shorter than add(a).add(b)