# Merge List<Keys> and List<Values> into List<Hashmap<Key,Value>>

Tags: list, dictionary, kotlin, collectors

i have two list;

```
val keys: List<String> = listOf("key1", "key2", "key3"...)
val values: List<String> = listOf("value1", "value2", "value3"...)
```

How can i merge them into one `List<Hashmap<Key,Value>>`? like;

`println(List<Hashmap<Key,Value>>)`: [[key1 = value1], [key2 = value2], [key3 = value3]...

Comment: The operation is called zip: https://www.baeldung.com/java-collections-zip

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I join two lists in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189559/how-do-i-join-two-lists-in-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In idiomatic Kotlin, that would look like this:

```
val keys: List<String> = listOf("key1", "key2", "key3")
val values: List<String> = listOf("value1", "value2", "value3")

val result = keys.zip(values).map { hashMapOf(it) }
```

<sup>[(runnable demo)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)</sup>

Here, [`hashMapOf(...)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/hash-map-of.html) accepts pairs (`Pair<K, V>`), and that's exactly the elements that `zip` produces.

Alternatively, you can use the overload of `zip` that accepts a lambda and maps the pairs without an additional call to `map`:

```
val result = keys.zip(values) { k, v -> hashMapOf(k to v) }
```

<sup>[(runnable demo)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)</sup>

The result is a list of maps, each containing a single key mapped to the value.

---

An opposite option is to create a single map containing all of the pairs, which can be produced as follows:

```
val result = HashMap(keys.zip(values).toMap())
```

<sup>[(runnable demo)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjcwIiwiY29kZSI6ImZ1biBtYWluKCkge1xuICAgIHZhbCBrZXlzOiBMaXN0PFN0cmluZz4gPSBsaXN0T2YoXCJrZXkxXCIsIFwia2V5MlwiLCBcImtleTNcIilcbiAgICB2YWwgdmFsdWVzOiBMaXN0PFN0cmluZz4gPSBsaXN0T2YoXCJ2YWx1ZTFcIiwgXCJ2YWx1ZTJcIiwgXCJ2YWx1ZTNcIilcblxuICAgIHZhbCByZXN1bHQgPSBIYXNoTWFwKGtleXMuemlwKHZhbHVlcykudG9NYXAoKSlcblxuICAgIHByaW50bG4ocmVzdWx0KVxufSIsInBsYXRmb3JtIjoianMiLCJhcmdzIjoiIiwianNDb2RlIjpudWxsfQ==)</sup>

Comment: @Tenfour04 Isn't that what the question author asked for? A list of hash maps, each containing a single key mapped to the value, I mean.

Comment: @hotkey It might be nice to include `keys.zip(values).toMap()` as well to illustrate that a single map is possible.

Comment: @Adam, thanks for the suggestion! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would have done like this.
Create your own class

```
class MyMap{
   String key;
   String value;
}
```

and then

```
 List<MyMap> newList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0;i<keys.size();i++){
      newList.add(new MyMap(keys.get(i),values.get(i)));
 }
```

Comment: This question is written in Kotlin, your answer is in Java.

Comment: tagged as java, so i thought might help, its just the syntax. thanx @Adm for pointing anyway.