# How to join two lists using java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have two list like

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("A","B");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("C","D");
```

I want to iterate both lists at the same time in java 8 and my output should be

A C
B D

Comment: You can find a lot of good answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189559/how-do-i-join-two-lists-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can create an IntStream to generate indices and then map each index to the String.

```
   IntStream.range(0, Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size()))
             .mapToObj(i -> list1.get(i)+" "+list2.get(i))
             .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Stream API as long as two `Iterator`s can do all you need:

```
Iterator<String> iterator1 = list1.iterator();
Iterator<String> iterator2 = list2.iterator();

while (iterator1.hasNext() && iterator2.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator1.next() + " " + iterator2.next());   // or add to a list
}
```