# Java8 - How to add List<List<String>> to List<List<String>>

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

I have two `List<List<String>>` and would like to concatenate them.

Here is my code:

```
List<List<String>> a = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
List<List<String>> b = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("d", "e", "f"));
a.addAll(b);
```

However, it doesn't work and throws an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
```

The code below works:

```
List<List<String>> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
List<List<String>> b = new ArrayList<>();
b.add(Arrays.asList("d", "e", "f"));
a.addAll(b);
```

What's the difference here?

Comment: Please update your question with a complete, runnable program which illustrates your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189559/how-do-i-join-two-lists-in-java

Comment: if `a.addAll(b)`  doesn't work, you're doing something wrong. Please [edit] and share the code you're executing

Comment: @azro All that matters is whether the outer list `a` is mutable or not, *and* whether the OP's input is what they really want to perform the transformation from.

Comment: `Arrays.asList` creates "*a fixed-size list*" as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) - for the next question "*doesn't work*" could be more specific (how does it not work) but "*throws an error*" is not enough, at least mention the exception, even better, include its Stack Trace!

Comment: "*What's the difference*" --> `Arrays.asList()` =!= `new ArrayList<>()` - first is a **method**, second is a **constructor** - first returns a `List` (instance of `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`, a nested class of `Arrays`), second creates an instance of `java.util.ArrayList` (not nested, different class as the first one, despite having the same name [unfortunately])

Comment: As @user16320675 mentioned, `Arrays.asList creates "a fixed-size list"`. This means you can't modify it afterwards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your attempt with `a.addAll(b)` works as long as the *outer list* `a` is mutable and you don't mind to modify it.

**Mutable outer list:**

```java
List<List<String>> a = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
        List.of("a", "b", "c"),
        List.of("d", "e", "f")));

List<List<String>> b = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
        List.of("h", "i", "j"),
        List.of("k", "l", "m")));

a.addAll(b); // the 'a' will contain all the inner lists

a.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Immutable outer list**

In case you want to preserve the former `a` and `b` lists and/or yield a new one, use [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream):

```java
List<List<String>> a = List.of(
        List.of("a", "b", "c"),
        List.of("d", "e", "f"));

List<List<String>> b = List.of(
        List.of("h", "i", "j"),
        List.of("k", "l", "m"));

List<List<String>> result = Stream.of(a, b)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Result**

Both ways share the same output:

> ```
> [a, b, c]
> [d, e, f]
> [h, i, j]
> [k, l, m]
> ```

Whether the inner lists are immutable or not doesn't matter for such combining.

Comment: *alternative* for last snippet: `Stream.concat(a.stream(), b.stream()).toList()` (newer Java); or `Stream.concat(a.stream(), b.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())` (before Java 16 [I think])

Comment: The `concat` seems a better choice. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because the `Arrays.asList()` returns

> a fixed-size list backed by the specified array

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

This means that when you try to add further elements, there is no space within the array representing the `List`; thus throwing an`UnsupportedOperationException`.

If you want to build `List` with specific elements and also be able to extend its size, then you should employ the class' Conversion Constructor by providing to it the lists returned by the `asList()` method.

```
List<List<String>> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"))));
List<List<String>> b = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("d", "e", "f"))));
a.addAll(b);
```

This way, both your outer and inner lists will behave as an actual `List` without throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` when exceeding the original size.

Answer (score -2):

You could avoid using the addAll function and iterate through b and add to a like shown below:

```
for(innerList:b){
   a.add(innerList);
}
```

Comment: same problem, I suspect...